# Regular Expression to test the presence and match a string at the same time

Tags: python, regex

I would like to determine whether a string S has a substring MYSUBSTRING preceded by two consecutive digits I need to determine.

For example:

'aaa79bbbMYSUBSTRINGccc'
==> I want 7, 9 and True (or 7, 9 and MYSUBSTRING)

'aaa79bbbccc'
==> I want 7, 9 and False (or 7, 9 and None)

Can I do that with a SINGLE regex? If so, which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following regex should do it:

`(\d)(\d)(?:.*?(MYSUBSTRING))?`

```
>>> re.search(r'(\d)(\d)(?:.*?(MYSUBSTRING))?', 'aaa79bbbMYSUBSTRINGccc').groups()
('7', '9', 'MYSUBSTRING')
>>> re.search(r'(\d)(\d)(?:.*?(MYSUBSTRING))?', 'aaa79bbbccc').groups()
('7', '9', None)
```

Comment: Why do I need the `?` in `.*?`? Isn't `'(\d)(\d)(?:.*(MYSUBSTRING))?'` enough?

Comment: More specifically, `r'^aaa(\d)(\d)bbb(?:(MYSUBSTRING))?ccc$` match the lines above and will fail if the line doesn't match that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use `(\d)(\d).*?(MYSUBSTRING)?`. In Python, you would use this in the `re.search` function like so:

```
s = ... # your string
m = re.search(r'(\d)(\d).*?(MYSUBSTRING)?', s)
m.group(1) # first digit
m.group(2) # second digit
m.group(3) # the substring, or None if it didn't match
```

Comment: Surely `m = re.search(r'(\d)(\d)bbb(MYSUBSTRING)?', s)`, given the examples above?

Comment: I don't speak python, but in perl it'd be: ^.*(\d)(\d).*((?:MYSUBSTRING))

Comment: Original solution fails to capture if there's intervening text. @Johnsyweb doesn't generalize (unless the solution isn't supposed to, in which case it's absolutely correct). @Brian Roach won't match anything if MYSUBSTRING doesn't appear, no? Of course, all of our solutions are so ugly it's probably best to do this in two regexes.

Comment: @Jacob: I deliberately didn't generalise. The regex I provided matches both of the examples above. I don't think these are real examples, so explicitly adding `bbb` should make it easier for @Sylvain to tailor.

Comment: @Jacob, @Johnsyweb: ah, I misread the question - I thought the substring had to be immediately preceded by the digits. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Fair enough. But the interesting part is making it work when you don't know what's going to go in place of the `bbb`!

Comment: Why do I need the `?` in `.*?`? Isn't `'(\d)(\d)(?:.*(MYSUBSTRING))?'` enough?

Comment: Sure, that'd work. But that version (without the extra `?`) will try to match the longest possible section of the string, which means that it will find the last instance of `MYSUBSTRING`. Unless that substring usually occurs toward the end of the entire string, it'll be marginally more efficient to use a reluctant quantifier (`*?`) to try to capture the shortest possible match, i.e. to make the regex find the first instance of `MYSUBSTRING` following the digits.

Answer (score 0):

A fun problem. This monstrosity:

```
(\d)(\d)(.(?!(MYSUBSTRING)))*.?(MYSUBSTRING)?
```

Seems to work for me.

Broken down:

```
(\d)(\d)              # capture 2 digits
(.(?!(MYSUBSTRING)))* # any characters not preceded by MYSUBSTRING
.?                    # the character immediately before MYSUBSTRINg
(MYSUBSTRING)?        # MYSUBSTRING, if it exists
```